# How can I get createSlice() to update my page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx, redux-toolkit

I'm creating a chatroom app, and I've been learning Redux Toolkit as I do it. I currently have text input that will go to the messages data object when 'Send' is clicked; however, I can't seem to get the page to update and render new messages. Anyone know why?

Reducer:

```
import { createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import chatData from '../../components/chatData'

export const chatSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'chat',
    initialState: chatData[0],
    reducers: {
        addChat: (state, action) => {
            if (action.payload !== '') {
                state.messages.push({
                    avatar: "#",
                    username: "",
                    message: action.payload
                })
                console.log('after', current(state))
            }
            console.log(action.payload);
        },
    },
});

export const { addChat } = chatSlice.actions

export const selectChat = state => state.messages

export default chatSlice.reducer
```

JSX:

```
<div>
    {props.chatData.messages.map((val, i) => {
        return <MessageBox username={val.username} avatar={val.avatar} message={val.message} />
    }
</div>
```

The state does update according to Redux DevTools and some console logging, but again, the page will not update accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the state did update in the store then I believe the issue is caused by your component:

1. You did not map the state to your component correctly, maybe typos?
2. The component’s shouldComponentUpdate method was modified to prevent rerendering of the component.